# lg webos tv grid layout - odd css behaviour

Tags: css, webos

I'm trying to create grid with items and facing this problem: (code here: [codepen](http://codepen.io/sangecz/pen/Wpdagr))
grid items are overlapping and ignoring margin as you can see in attached screenshot from emulator, on tv it's the same.

I tried that codepen in other browsers (ff, chrome, chromium, opera, safari) and none of them overlapped grid items.

I thought that `display: flex` could be the cause but it seams to work fine, without it grid items' divs are correctly on top of each other.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I also posted this question directly on webos tv forum and I got this answer:

> This is a bug of the old version of Chrome.   If you reduce the width
>   of the grid-row-item from 384 to 340 or lower, it will be displayed
>   normally.   For your information, you can test it with a lower
>   chromium browser version than #44 here:
>   https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win/299976/

It did that trick but I also had to reduce number of elems displayed on a page. This issue has been repeating again when I've had divs outside of the visible area of the browser window - this happened because I rotate underlying array containing data for these divs (simulation of moving grid under one fixed focused elem).